# Single SPA - Handle error in nested micro front end

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parcel, micro-frontend, single-spa

MFE = micro-front-end

I'm trying to import 1 MFE to another MFE.
**MFE-food** calls **MFE-cart**.
When MFE-cart is down, there is an impact on MFE-food, my expectation is MFE should run properly.

in **root-config**, I have added

```
addErrorHandler(err => {
  if (getAppStatus(err.appOrParcelName) === LOAD_ERROR) {
    System.delete(System.resolve(err.appOrParcelName));
  }
});
```

in console, there is an error message like this.
I must handle this error so MFE-food can run independently whether **MFE-cart** is running or not

```
system.js:654 GET http://localhost:9006/hotel-cart.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED 200
system.js:637 Uncaught (in promise) Error: application '@hotel/food' died in status LOADING_SOURCE_CODE: Error loading http://localhost:9006/hotel-cart.js from http://localhost:9005/hotel-food.js (SystemJS Error#3 https://git.io/JvFET#3)
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (system.js:637)
```

Comment: First, put a try catch block around your code that catches that Promise rejection. Then, inside that catch block (or chained method), throw an [Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw). Then you can have a handler deal with the custom error.